# Extracting info from QuerySnapshot variable in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This code is running fine with futurebuilder and i m getting a listview properly.
But i want to see into the documents n print the details in console. I m not getting any idea about how to do this with QuerySnapshot variable.

```
Future getP() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;
  var q = await firestore.collection('place_list').getDocuments();
  print(q.documents);
  return q.documents;
}
```

I think I have to call it n wait for the responses then print them, can anyone guide me how to do it?

[image: This is the co]

[image: This is what i am getting when i try to print the values to console]

Comment: have you tried q.documents.toString()? let me know if it works i will post it as an anwer

Comment: Yes, I tried it...it is printing same thing as string instead of list/array... @Henok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = 
  q.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc){
  return doc.data;
}).toList();

print(list);
```

Comment: Yes, it is working fine. But I am not getting all the documents present in my firestore db collection. First 10 or so entries are getting printed in console. But I am getting all 300 entries in `futurebuilder` `listview`...

Comment: @IROC I am glad it's working, that's for another question. Post another question about not getting  the whole data and comment the link here I will try to help there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60411928/extracting-a-large-number-about-300-documents-from-a-firebase-firestore-db-col

Here is the link to question @Henok

Answer (score 3):

Though the answer is right the current firebase API has changed drastically now to access QuerySnapshot one can follow the below code.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.get()
.then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc["first_name"]);
    });
});
```

And if you are using `async/await` then first you need to resolve the `AsyncSnapshot` and then work on it. If you like:

```
    return FutureBuilder(
    future: PropertyService(uid:userId).getUserProperties(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text("Something went wrong");
      }

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {

        snapshot.data.docs.forEach((element) {
          Property property = Property.fromJson(element.data());
        });
        return Text("Demo Text");

      }

      return LoadingPage();
    }
);
```

taken from [url](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots)

Answer (score 1):

//But I am not getting all the documents present in my firestore DB collection. The first 10 or so entries are getting printed in the console. //

I think that is standard behavior. If you have one million records it can't print everything in console. To check any particular set of documents you have to filter through where condition in query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have still this problem, I hope this will help you.

This is how I get data from QuerySnapshot:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot =
    await userCollection.where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).get();

List<Object?> data = snapshot.docs.map((e) {
    return e.data();
}).toList();

Map<dynamic, dynamic> userData = data[0] as Map;

print(userData["email"]);
```

Or you can easily get data by:

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
    await userCollection.where("uid", isEqualTo: uid).get();
print(querySnapshot.docs[0)['fieldName']);
```