# Extracting a large number (about 300) documents from a firebase firestore db collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from firestore. The code is working fine in `FutureBuilder ListView`.I tried printing all the entries to console. The code below is working fine but only printing first 10 or so entries.

```
Future getP() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;
  var q = await firestore.collection('place_list').getDocuments();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> list = q.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return doc.data;
  }).toList();
  print(list);
  return q.documents;
}
```

[image: The code :]

[image: The console output :]

I want to get all 300 entries to be printed in console. Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Split data to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **debugPrint** instead of *print*

```
debugPrint(list.toString(), wrapWidth: 1024);
```

or add this method and

```
void printWrapped(String text) {
  final pattern = new RegExp('.{1,800}'); // 800 is the size of each chunk
  pattern.allMatches(text).forEach((match) => print(match.group(0)));
}
```

call

> printWrapped(list.toString());

Check [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665) for further information.